# Knex Queries Not Running

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I am trying to get a basic query in **knex** working but it's not executing the select or returning an error.

```
const knexfile = require('./knexfile.js');
knex = require('knex')(knexfile.development);

knex('views').select()
.then((data) => {
    console.log('test);
    console.log(data);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I run it, I don't see any output. I have migrations setup and those are working fine so the config file is good. The table also has data in it.

**Why am I not getting any data back from my query?**

Comment: tried your script there (and fixed the typo on 'test which should give you an fair error) and got a reasonable knex error output. try to init another npm project just to see if the error is the same. there i got this: https://pastebin.com/bvifNZrN

Comment: This code should work (accept for typo in `'test`). Try to add console.log('foo') before the call to be sure that execution is reaching this point.

Comment: In the docs, the syntax for select queries is `knex.select().from('views')`. The `knex('views')` syntax is used for inserts, updates etc. I'm not sure if the latter syntax also works for selects.